# Can I have a listener for the physical hardware button that is present on the side of the Android watch?

Tags: android, wear-os

My android watch has a single hardware (physical) button on the side. Is it possible to program a listener for this button, so that it can be used as an additional control in my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible. The usual way to detect a standard button press (like Back) in Android is with an `onKeyDown` listener, and this doesn't fire in an `Activity` on Wear when the stem button is pressed (tested on both Wear 1.5 and the 2.0 dev preview).

It's always iffy to assert something is categorically not possible, because there's always the chance that someone will find a clever hack to make it happen. And I wouldn't mind being proved wrong. But until such a hack comes along, I'm going to say no, it's not.

Comment: I agree with String that we do not recommend developers override the default action. Some watches have more than one button, e.g. Polar M600. At the moment, this is only open to OEM to customised BUT we would love to hear if there're other use-cases developers are working on. Please do share with us if possible and I will feed it back to the product team. No promises though...

Comment: It's raining / the user is wearing gloves touch screen interaction becomes really hard.  It's blowing a gale so not good for voice stuff either.  There is a reason why serious fitness / outdoors watches have a load of physical buttons on them.  Or say the watch is properly waterproof and the user is scuba diving with it...  You need physical buttons.

Comment: @Hoi is there any way for a custom activity or watchface to intercept presses of this secondary button on the Polar M600? I would like it to trigger non-OEM behaviour ;)